# Include .css files in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio

Since virturl directory name is not fixed, I wrote code below to include .css file in .aspx page now.

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Css/xxx.css") %>" type="text/css" />
```

The question is, when I use "ResolveUrl" in  tag, IDE is always barking about that all CSS classes is undefined.

Is there any better way to define .css file including?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this with html server controls (notice the `runat="server"`) like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/css/styles.css" />
```

This will still resolve the virtual directory for you. It should also support the css  intellisense and warnings on the aspx page.

Comment: The tilde (~) URL syntax requires runat="server".

Comment: The tilde works on the `link` tag without `runat="server"` if that is set on the `head` tag instead, i.e. `<head runat="server">`. I actually cannot get it to work if it is not set on the `head` tag and only on the `link` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can include the files statically inside `<% if (false) { %>`.

This way, Visual Studio's IntelliSense will see the files, but the ASP.Net runtime will not.
(And the `if (false)` block should be optimized away by the compiler, so there should be zero performance hit)

Comment: Arrrr you typed faster than me! This is the best solution IMO. You can continue referencing files the way you are now and then duplicate all of your references using physical paths and wrap the duplicates  in an `if(false) { }`

Answer (score 0):

The IDE will not know that you are including that css file, simply because it will generate in runtime, not before it.

If you need the intelisense put it manually and change later when you need.